# Replace regex with part of the regex after match Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following html:

```
<span class='token-item' style='" + token_style + "'>" + token + "</span>
```

I want to replace the whole string with the string "%" + token + "%".

So far, I got this:

```
html.replace(/<span class=\"token-item\"[^>]*(.*)</span>/g, "%" + "\1" + "%" );
```

However it does not work. Is there a way to replace the regex with part of the regex?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html.replace("/<span class='token-item'[^>]*?>(.*)</span>/g", "%" + "\1" + "%" );
```

I made a few slight changes to what you had originally.  You had `token-item` in double quotes in your original regex, but your sample used single quotes.  Also, the regex pattern needs to be in double quotes.  I made the character class `[^>]*` non greedy by adding a `?` after it.  Without this, I fear your original regex would consume everything until the final `<span>` tag.

You can test the regex here:

```
<span class='token-item'[^>]*?>(.*)</span>
```

## Regex101

Answer (score 0):

You can search the string for the span element repeatedly, get the first match, then use another regex to get the token within the match then replace the first match with that token. Do this until you find no more span elements within the string.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function replaceWithToken(input) {
        var spanEx = /<span class='token-item'[^>]*>[^<>]*<\/span>/;
        var tokenEx = />.*</;
        var output = input;
        while (true) {
            var matches = spanEx.exec(output);

            //if no more span element found, stop
            if (matches == null || matches.length == 0)
                break;

            var span = matches[0];
            //get the token from the match, in the form of >token<
            var token = tokenEx.exec(span)[0];

            //remove the > and < and add % in front and back
            token = '%' + token.substring(1, token.length - 1) + '%';

            //replace the first match with the token
            output = output.replace(span, token);
        }

        return output;
    }
    var input = "<span class='token-item' style='token_style'>this is the first token</span>"
        + "<br /><span class='token-item'>this is the second token</span>";
    var output = replaceWithToken(input);
    console.log(input);
    console.log(output);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex also :  `/<span class=\'token-item\'[^>]*?>.*?(\w+).*?<\/span>/g`

[Demo and Explain](https://regex101.com/r/oG6yL3/10)

Code Sample :

```js
token = "sampleToken";
token_style = "none;"

html = "<span class='token-item' style='" +token_style+ "'>" + token +"</span>";
re = /<span class=\'token-item\'[^>]*?>.*?(\w+).*?<\/span>/g;

console.log(html);
console.log(html.replace(re,"%$1%"));
```